# Adding comma to setinterval counter value

Tags: javascript, parseint

the title might not be the right one, sorry about that.

I'm trying to make a livecounter for a website, the idea it's to show a fake number increasing every second. I've this so far

```js
var START_DATE = new Date("November 27, 2014 13:30"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 2; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 901; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0; //finally this shit is working

window.onload = function()
{
 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
 var now = new Date();
 count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
 setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;", msInterval);
}
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Which is shows a number like "24350919" increasing each second, I want to convert it to 24,350,919. I tried with parseFloat, but I couldn't make it work.

Can someone give me a hand with this? thank you!

Comment: use `.toLocaleString()`

Comment: If you don't want to depend on user's browser localization and wants to always show the same pattern, you can use something like this `"24358703".match(/\d{1,3}/g).join(",")` but I don't know how to fix the regex for your pattern.

Comment: Yeah, but if I do that, it will be the same number increasing every time I refresh the browser, I wanna show a constant number increasing each day, forever. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:-**

```js
var START_DATE = new Date("November 27, 2014 13:30"); // put in the starting date here
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds
var INCREMENT = 2; // increase per tick
var START_VALUE = 901; // initial value when it's the start date
var count = 0; //finally this shit is working


window.onload = function() {
  var msInterval = INTERVAL * 1000;
    var now = new Date();
    count = parseInt((now - START_DATE)/msInterval) * INCREMENT + START_VALUE;
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);
    setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = addCommas(count);", msInterval);
}

function addCommas(myStr)
{
    myStr += '';
    var x = myStr.split('.');
    var x1 = x[0];
    var x2 = x.length > 1 ? '.' + x[1] : '';
    var rgx = /(\d+)(\d{3})/;
    while (rgx.test(x1)) {
        x1 = x1.replace(rgx, '$1' + ',' + '$2');
    }
    return x1 + x2;
}
```

```html
<div id="counter"></div>
```

---

You can try to use `toLocaleString()` like this:

```
var n = 24350919
n.toLocaleString()
```

In your case it would be like

```
setInterval("count += INCREMENT; document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML =
         count;", msInterval.toLocaleString());
```

Comment: Thank youi for your reply, what it does it's to update more frequently and faster. But what I need, it's to show the "," like 24,350,919.

Answer (score 1):

Try `.toLocaleString()`

```
msInterval.toLocaleString()
```

Comment: Thank youi for your reply, what it does it's to update more frequently and faster. But what I need, it's to show the "," like 24,350,919